# Phone number updated algorithm

Tags: android, mysql, algorithm

I have an app where visitors register from their phone numbers (much like WhatsApp or Telegram). I store the number in e164 format.

Once he is connected, the application synchronizes his contacts with the database in order to see which contact is using the application. during synchronization the application retrieves the list of numbers from its phonebook and converts them into E.164 format before sending them to the server. so far everything is working fine.

Here is where the problem arises: recently, a country (the Ivory Coast) has decided to change its phone numbers from 8 digits to 10 digits. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Assuming you have the numbers of the users, check for their country code & if you use any mechanism to connect with your users (like FCM or Remote Config), you can easily ask them whatever you want.

Comment: Maybe don't bother with e164

Answer (score 0):

Treat a phone number as an arbitrary value until you can verify it works. Countries change the structure of their telephone numbers all the time and in unpredictable ways.

What is valid one day may not be valid the next. What rules apply one day may not apply the next. There is absolutely no way of knowing what might happen.

Phone numbers do not really adhere to any standard at all. E.164 only establishes the calling prefix, so that's something that *might* follow standards, but even those can change arbitrarily as countries get created, or merge.

In other words, this is all political and there is no way of predicting the future.